# How do I Suppress "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed" message in sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Is there a way that you can have SERVEROUTPUT set to ON in sqlplus but somehow repress the message "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed" that is automatically generated upon completed execution of a plsql procedure?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use the command:

```
SET FEEDBACK OFF
```

before running the procedure.  And afterwards you can turn it back on again:

```
SET FEEDBACK ON
```

Comment: and obviously `SET FEEDBACK ON` to re-enable it

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, but why do you have to turn it back on? I mean, that's only if you want it on for something else in the same script, right? If you don't want _any_ output from some script, you can just turn it off, and forget about it. It will default to `ON` in other places, right? Or is setting it to `OFF` like some system-wide setting or something?

Comment: @osullic you don't have to, but since it is the default setting you may want to return to it so that you get useful feedback when running code manually.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked well for me in sqlplus, but I did just notice that "set feedback off" suppresses errors in Sql Developer (at least version 17.2.0.188). Just something to be aware of if you use Sql Developer:

```
create or replace procedure test_throw_an_error as buzz number; begin dbms_output.put_line('In test_throw_an_error. Now, to infinity!'); buzz:=1/0; end;
/
set serveroutput on
set feedback off
exec test_throw_an_error;
exec dbms_output.put_line('Done, with feedback off');
set feedback on
exec test_throw_an_error;
exec dbms_output.put_line('Done, with feedback on');
```

Result:

```
Procedure TEST_THROW_AN_ERROR compiled

In test_throw_an_error. Now, to infinity!

Done, with feedback off

In test_throw_an_error. Now, to infinity!


Error starting at line : 11 in command -
BEGIN test_throw_an_error; END;
Error report -
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ORA-06512: at "ECTRUNK.TEST_THROW_AN_ERROR", line 1
ORA-06512: at line 1
01476. 00000 -  "divisor is equal to zero"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Done, with feedback on

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```